# Deep links in Spotify as the best practice

Tags: macos, safari, spotify, deep-linking, custom-protocol

I am researching the way Spotify registers its custom protocol scheme in macOS Catalina (Spotify URI).

Spotify uses custom URIs of the following format (notice the **absence of slashes**)

```
spotify:track:2nI9BfzCrSWZnCkpF2Nn6O
```

When I take this link and paste it in the Safari address bar, Safari recognizes it as a valid link and navigates to the app correctly.

None of other custom protocol schemes I have checked on macOS are recognized by Safari in the same way (if no slashes are present).

The [general recommendation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-102207-TPXREF115) is to include the scheme in the apps `Info.plist` file. I have 
tried that as well, but a deep link with no slashes was not recognized - Safari runs a web search instead.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by a friend, this seems to be a one-off fix specifically for Spotify, as 'spotify' is whitelisted in `SafariShared.framework`:

[image: hopper]

As you can see, the custom protocol is hardcoded.